# Pandas - Replace values in a DataFrame Based on a Boollean DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm using Pandas v0.20.2 and I have DataFrame, like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[0,1], b=[3,4], c=[6,7]), 
              index=['spam', 'ham'])
#       a  b  c
# spam  0  3  6
# ham   1  4  7
```

And I have another DataFrame that is a mask:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[True,False], b=[True,True]), 
                index=['spam', 'ham'])
#           a     b
# spam   True  True
# ham   False  True
```

And I want to set the values in `df` equal to `999` where it is `True` in the `mask`.

I thought that the following would work:

```
df[mask] = 999
```

But it doesn't. I get the error below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-503f937859ab> in <module>()
----> 1 df[mask] = 999

/home/gbra/anaconda3/envs/outer_disk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2326             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   2327         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
-> 2328             self._setitem_frame(key, value)
   2329         else:
   2330             # set column

/home/gbra/anaconda3/envs/outer_disk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _setitem_frame(self, key, value)
   2364         self._check_inplace_setting(value)
   2365         self._check_setitem_copy()
-> 2366         self._where(-key, value, inplace=True)
   2367 
   2368     def _ensure_valid_index(self, value):

/home/gbra/anaconda3/envs/outer_disk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, try_cast, raise_on_error)
   5096             for dt in cond.dtypes:
   5097                 if not is_bool_dtype(dt):
-> 5098                     raise ValueError(msg.format(dtype=dt))
   5099 
   5100         cond = cond.astype(bool, copy=False)

ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Seems to work for me on pandas 0.19.2 and python 2.7.

Comment: @Psidom I had the feeling that this worked too. But I guess it stopped after I updated Pandas, but I cannot be sure. I am refactoring old code. I've updated the question.

Comment: Throwing error in pandas 0.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reindex the mask to have the same shape as df, and then use `df.mask`:

```
df.mask(mask.reindex(df.index, df.columns, fill_value=False), 999)
Out: 
        a    b  c
spam  999  999  6
ham     1  999  7
```

At that point, regular indexing should also work:

```
df[mask.reindex(df.index, df.columns, fill_value=False)] = 999
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[0,1], b=[3,4], c=[6,7]), 
              index=['spam', 'ham'])
mask = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[True,False], b=[True,True]), 
                index=['spam', 'ham'])
df.iloc[mask] = 999
```

Then `df` is

```
        a   b     c
spam    999 999   6
ham     1   999   7
```

Comment: Thanks, Miriam. But I get all cells equal to 999.

Comment: Wow that definitely strange. My pandas version is 0.20.2 and my python version is 2.7.12 and it worked for me.

Comment: Other than the depreciation warning, works for me too (0.20.1).

Comment: I created a new conda environment with python 2.7.13 and pandas 0.20.2 and now I get that the DataFrame does not change at all. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without updating `mask`

```
df[mask.columns] = df[mask.columns].mask(mask, 999)
```